# writing hive query results to hdfs

Tags: hive, hdfs

I can export a hive query results using this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/home/user/events/'
```

but if I want to export it to an HDFS dir at `/user/events/`

how do I do that? I tried this:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/user/events/'
> row format delimited 
> fields terminated by '\t' 
> select * from table;
```

but get this error then:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 2:0 cannot recognize input near 'row' 'format' 'delimited' in statement
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `LOCAL` keyword - it specifies local filesystem. Without it the result will go to hdfs. You may actually need to use `OVERWRITE` though. So:

`INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/user/events/'`

Comment: so I tried that with row delimited but got an error...I updated the question to include it...

Comment: format specification is only available in ```LOCAL``` mode. In non local mode (what you need) it's only available from hive version 1.2.0 (if I'm not mistaken), so if you use an older version you're out of luck... see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5672

Comment: so what does hive use then for the delimiter?

Comment: it uses binary 1 (0x01) for field separator.

Comment: it's a non printable character. Just like an alphabet character, but not visible. Just like a linefeed (newline), for example. see: http://www.asciitable.com